# How do I mount the correct drive everytime the Raspberry Pi reboots?

Tags: hard-drive, mount

I generally know how to mount hard drives in a UNIX system. But I am confused with one thing. Say I have `disk #1` and `disk #2`. I mount `disk #1` with `sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/drive`. How will I know that `sda1` will be assigned to `disk #1` and not `disk #2`, especially after when the Raspberry Pi restarts? In other words, how can I have `sda1` and `sdb1` assigned to disk #1 and #2 respectively and prevent it from swapping with each other after reboot?

Comment: This is a good question because on a multidisk system /dev/sda isn't always /dev/sda after a reboot.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Disk drives are distinguished by their UUID(universally unique identifier). 
You can find the UUID of your HDs with the command `ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid/` 
Then you must create the mount points `sudo mkdir /MOUNT/POINT1` 
and change the permissions of them `sudo chmod 775 /MOUNT/POINT1`
Then you add a line to your fstab file (which is located at /etc/fstab) wich looks like that:

```
UUID=BLAHBLAH12341234 /MOUNT/POINT1 ntfs-3g rw,defaults 0 0
UUID=12341234BLAHBLAH /MOUNT/POINT2 ext rw,defaults 0 0
```

Of course you have to change it according to your file system etc.
Then save the file and reboot and your HDs will mount automatically to the given mount points.

Comment: As I pointed out in my answer, it is not the drives, but the partitions on the drives that are identified by a UUID. (A subtle difference.) If you re-format a drive, that creates a new partition which gets a new UUID.

Comment: What do you mean by "**/MOUNT/POINT1**"?  Is that the literal definition of the mount point?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky its just the name of the folder you want to mount your partitions. Choose as you like.

Comment: Better than just restarting is to execute `sudo mount -a`and see if there are any errors. If there were any, it could lead to a system that does not boot.

Answer (score 9):

This is strictly a generic Linux question, but the answer anyway is partition UUIDs (Universally Unique Identifiers). Like the name says on the tin, when a partition is formatted, a random unique ID is generated that describes it. You can use this to mount to ensure that you always get the correct partition. The `blkid` command gives a list of UUIDs for currently attached devices, e.g:

```
/dev/sda4: UUID="2d02d277-a79c-4818-adc7-c37484e17c6a" TYPE="ext3"
```

This will correspond to a /dev device, in this case `/dev/disk/by-uuid/2d02d277-a79c-4818-adc7-c37484e17c6a`. You can use that to mount. You can use a slightly shorter notation with in `/etc/fstab` to specify that a drive should be mounted:

```
UUID=2d02d277-a79c-4818-adc7-c37484e17c6a /mnt/backup ext3 defaults 0 0
```

See [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-finding-using-uuids-to-update-fstab/) for more details, or look at [UUID search results here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/search?q=uuid).

Comment: When I type **blkid**, I get nothing!

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky Try `sudo blkid`. Apparently `blkid` requires root privileges, but on a Raspberry Pi by default you will log in as the non-privileged user `pi`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the workaround gabriel, same problem here (Raspberry 2).
But I could skip out on the 30 seconds by time the rc.local got to work the device was found, so a

```
sudo mount -a
```

in the /etc/rc.local did the job.

Answer (score -1):

Well , true and not true
In my case , RPI v2 4 core ,something has changed since  v1 version as such:
editing fstab in order to automount external hdd at start does not run at all , not using uuid , not using /dev/sda1

the problem is that i have to wait 30 seconds after complete boot in order to mount my external hdd drive , weird is that on USB stick , fstab runs flawlessly.
So , i did a script to sleep 30 ; sudo mount -a to run things out .

here is /etc/fstab

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ cat /etc/fstab 
proc            /proc           proc    defaults          0       0
/dev/mmcblk0p1  /boot           vfat    defaults          0       2
/dev/mmcblk0p2  /               ext4    defaults,noatime  0       1
# a swapfile is not a swap partition, so no using swapon|off from here on, use  dphys-swapfile swap[on|off]  for that
```

And added last line

> ```
> UUID=3d81d9e2-7d1b-4015-8c2c-29ec0875f762 /media/250_gb ext4 defaults 0 0
> ```

Here is my /etc/rc.local   extension

```
# Begin all drives remount
clear
echo "Please wait 30 seconsds in order to remount all missing drives !!!"
for x in `seq 1 30`
do
echo -n "."
sleep 1
done
sudo mount -a
sudo service minidlna force-reload

# End drives remount 

exit 0
```

It could be something with jmicron usb adapter, without 30 sec wait it says that device is not present even though lsusb gets correct Jmicron adapter
Got to dig it deep underground !!!

Here are 2 of  my TV snapshots
Before
[image]
after
[image]

gabriel@linux-romania.com

Comment: The question speaks about disk ordering and not about not available device.

Comment: Not sure why you got downvoted.  I noticed this same problem.  I have not a problem with SSD.  The problem comes when I mount disk drive.  Ended up writing a script to delay the mounting to get it to work.