# Connect external hdd ExFat

Tags: raspbian, linux, hard-drive, mount

I'm trying to connect my external hdd which is in ExFat, but it won't mount it.
I've got "*fuse:device not found*", but if i do *fdisk -l*, I can see it.
Can someone know how to fit it ?

Or if you have an idea to mount a hdd in exfat, i take it :).

Comment: Have you tried this: https://www.howtogeek.com/235655/how-to-mount-and-use-an-exfat-drive-on-linux/ (i.e., Did you try a search engine first, lol?).   It looks like basically: `sudo apt install exfat-utils exfat-fuse` should do it.

Comment: And now we arrived on a loop, search engines brought me to this question :)

Answer (score 1):

You can add the UUID in /etc/fstab similar to this:

```
## Western Digital My Book
UUID=F577-20E3  /mnt/mybook     exfat   defaults,nofail 0       1
```

Separated by tabs, NOT spaces. NOFAIL option allows the operating system to continue to boot regardless of errors from the drive (missing, corrupt etc.)

Instructions here:
https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/14623/27509